# Debug.log suddenly appearing in Windows 7 folder

Tags: windows-7

I have a folder on my desktop that contains 2,500 mp3 files. Lately, debug.log shows up after I edit a file. This is what it says:

[0727/073747.181:ERROR:crash_report_database_win.cc(469)] failed to stat report
[0727/073747.182:ERROR:crash_report_database_win.cc(469)] failed to stat report

There are several dozen of these entries.
What does "failed to stat" mean?

Comment: If you can reproduce it, can you run Process Monitor at the same time.  Then filter down to the file operations where the file is created.  Ideally setup symbols but you should see the stack and therefore the modules at play that caused the file to be generated.  If you need help, maybe link a .PML file of the file being created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [debug.log file is being created in a few Windows folders (possibly from Chrome). How can I troubleshoot and resolve?](https://superuser.com/questions/1241154/debug-log-file-is-being-created-in-a-few-windows-folders-possibly-from-chrome)